# Transform xorcrypto encryption module to AES encryption module

Tags: c, encryption, network-programming, openssl, aes

I have been given a sample encryption module which simply xor a key with the packet data and place the result in data field of constructed packet itself....

The code for xoricv module is here.

```
void
xorcrypto(uint8_t *key, uint32_t keylen,
    uint8_t *data, uint32_t datalen)
{
    int d, k;

    for (d=0, k=0; d < datalen; ++d, k = (k+1)%keylen) {
            data[d] ^= key[k];
    }
}
```

Now i need to change the module so that it performed the AES Encryption rather than simple xor operation.

Would you suggest possible transformation i need to do  ????

It is a small part of my project and i am stuck in between..

The AES Command I have used on command line for encryption

openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in file.txt -out file.enc

Daily i am going through plenty of errors when i tried to implement it by my own and i have very limited time so please help me.......

---

Here is my implementation ...... although i am adding it here in answer column because may be there is small bug in my implementation which i could be able to solve through some valuable suggestions but still If any other way is possible please suggest and provide me some implementation code...

```
/* u_int8_t ... etc all are typedefs for uint8_t....etc 
 so don't bother about them */

void xorcrypto(u_int8_t *key, u_int32_t keylen,u_int8_t *data,
               u_int32_t datalen)
{

int ch,i,j;
uint8_t modata[100];

FILE *fp,*fr,*fq,*ft;

fp=fopen("key","w");
fputs((char *)key,fp);
fq=fopen("file.txt","w");
fputs((char *)data,fq);

fclose(fp);
fclose(fq);

system("sudo openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in file.txt -out file.enc -pass file:key");

fr=fopen("file.enc","r");

memset(data,0,sizeof(data));

i=0;

while( (ch=fgetc(fr))==EOF) {
   data[i]=ch;
   i++;
}

fclose(fr);

system("sudo openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -salt -in file.enc 
 -out file1.txt -pass file:key");


ft=fopen("file1.txt","r");

memset(modata,0,sizeof(modata));

j=0;

while( (ch=fgetc(ft)) != EOF) {
            modata[j]=ch;
            j++;
}

fclose(ft);

}
```

Call to function in module is described as -

```
bool
espcrypto(esp_private *epriv, sendip_data *data, sendip_data *pack)
{
    u_int32_t keylen;
    u_int8_t *key;
    static u_int8_t fakekey;
    struct ip_esp_hdr *esp = (struct ip_esp_hdr *)pack->data;

    if (!epriv->keylen) {   /* This isn't going to be very productive... */
            key = &fakekey;
            keylen = 1;
    } else {
            key = (u_int8_t *)epriv->key;
            keylen = epriv->keylen;
    }
    /* Encrypt everything past the ESP header */
    xorcrypto(key, keylen,
            (u_int8_t *)esp->enc_data,
                    pack->alloc_len + data->alloc_len -
                            sizeof(struct ip_esp_hdr));
    return TRUE;
    }
```

This is code in the xorcrypto.c file in packet generator tool i am using which is linked during packet construction through command line as `-am xorcrypto.so` .That is the reason why I was being so lazy.I am first looking for an implementation which can act as proof of concept .Rest all optimizations can be done later.

The output I am getting is - encryption not performed at all the data is still in plain text                      in packet.

```
udit@udit-Dabba ~/Downloads/sendip-2.5-mec-2/mec $ cat file.txt 
udit@udit-Dabba ~/Downloads/sendip-2.5-mec-2/mec $ cat file.enc 
Salted__����
}�#��G�����0����iudit@udit-Dabba ~/Downloads/sendip-2.5-mec-2/mec $ cat file1.txt
udit@udit-Dabba ~/Downloads/sendip-2.5-mec-2/mec $
```

Why file.txt is null even `key` file is not updated ???

If any other information needed i will add it here......but please help me getting out of the mesh .

Comment: If you want to be really lazy: `system("openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in file.txt -out file.enc"); // TODO: refactor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

I feel the line :

```
while( (ch=fgetc(fr))==EOF)
// Also, Similar statements that you have used many times.
```

You are reading 1 character from the file and comparing that to `EOF`. That works fine untill you are working with normal text files.

But here you are working with an encrypted file, `file.enc` which can contain anything at all.
It can even posses `EOF` character itself as data content.

That means if file has 100 characters and 2nd character is `EOF` then it will terminate at 2nd character itself.

I feel this as a possible problem.

Remains.. the other problems - I suggest using `fprintf()` instead of `fputs()`, these are easy to use and hence avoids unseen bugs. Since you are working on strings instead of characters logically.

Moreover, using these you also get an advantage of string formatting when needed.

Try out and then get back.. :)

Answer (score 2):

This may not even be possible without making some additional changes to your software.  It doesn't look like your function allows for the resulting encrypted data to be larger than the unencrypted data, for one, which will be required for RSA.

The key you pass to your function will also be quite different; one side of an RSA key will consist of the modulus and an exponent.  The modulus will be a large number (not representable with the normal integer types), and the exponent is typically a large number for one side and a (relatively) small one for the other.

Aside from that, there are a number of issues and difficulties with RSA.  You could try to deal with these yourself, but you'd probably be better off using an existing library like OpenSSL.  Some of these issues include:

- Implementing RSA (with usefully long keys) requires modular arithmetic on very large numbers, far larger than any of the normal integer types.  You'd either have to write functions for this, or find a library.
- The data has to be broken into pieces that are shorter than the modulus (part of the key), including whatever padding and such is encrypted along with the data.  The length of each piece after encryption will be the length of the modulus.  That's why the resulting encrypted data will be longer than the original data (and also padding).
- Avoiding certain vulnerabilities requires additional steps, such as adding random padding into each piece of data and ensuring that the padded data, raised to the exponent from the key, would exceed the modulus (if it weren't done as modular exponentiation).

So first, you'll need to make it possible for your encryption function to return more data than you gave it.  Then you should probably look at using an encryption library to do the actual encryption, to save a lot of work and reduce the chances of letting vulnerabilities slip through.

Comment: would you suggest any other encryption method which may work here...look i am looking for any encryption method which would be fine for network applications and please help me with some implementating code.if any one would work then atleast i can follow that to others working.

Comment: Since RSA is also kind of slow, it's generally used to encrypt small amounts of data such as a key for a block cipher to be used for the rest of the data.  AES is probably a good one, but using an encryption library like OpenSSL to do the work is still a good idea unless there's a good reason you have to do it yourself.  I'm sure there are others here who know more about this topic than I do if any of them care to answer, though.

Comment: What's the connection between RSA and AES? The question was about replacing XOR with AES, and RSA wasn't mentioned at all.

Comment: He originally asked about RSA... he changed it to AES later.